# Use loop to render three column image gallery with no set number of images

Tags: for-loop, twig

I am outputting images from a gallery created with WordPress and Advanced Custom Fields. The following code is displaying two images per column, with the columns repeating until there are no more images to display. I am needing to set a max of three columns with all of the images displayed within those columns.

```
<div class="grid">
  {% for image in story.meta( 'gallery' ) %}
    {% if loop.index % 2 == 1 %}
      <div class="post__gallery-column">
    {% endif %}
        <figure>
          <img src="{{ Image(image) }}" width="{{ Image(image).width }}" height="{{ Image(image).height }}" alt="{{ Image(image).alt }}" />
        </figure>
    {% if loop.index % 2 == 0 or loop.last %}
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Visual representation:

[image: Image columns example]

How can I adjust the code to set a hard limit on the number of columns rendered on the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a max of 3 columns, you could use the filter [batch](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/batch.html). This splits your array in even chunks.

```
{% set max_cols = 3 %}
{% set images_per_col = (images|length / max_cols)|round(0, 'ceil') %}

<div class="grid">
    {% for images in images|batch(images_per_col) %}
    <div class="post__gallery-column">
        {% for image in images %}
        <figure>
            <img src="{{ image }}" />
        </figure>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/tcbshp)

---

*If `story.meta('gallery')` is not `Iterable`, you would need to convert this to an array first*